# Python: assert if variable is in multiple lists

Tags: python, list, assert

I'm trying to make an assertion where it would raise an error if there is more than one variable in a dictionary of lists.

I've written it like below for now but I was wondering if someone could suggest a way to shorten it.

```
assert_counter = 0
l = ['a','b','c']
d = {'list1':['a'], 'list2':['b', 'c'], 'list3':['a']}

for variable in l:
   assert_counter = 0
   for inside in d:
       if (variable in d[inside]):
           assert_counter = assert_counter + 1
           assert assert_counter > 1, (str(variable) + " is in more than one list")
```

Comment: The code you have given does not run. It is very useful to have a working code to start with, or perhaps you want to re-word your question to be about the errors in your code?

Comment: Assertions get removed when running the code in optimized mode, don't use them for actual programming, just use them to be sure you code it right. Use raise if ytou want to get an exception

Comment: also don't use `list` and `dict` as variables.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon oops :/ this was part of a bigger script which I simplified to ask the question here. Thanks for the pointer, I've edited it :P

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sorry I'm very new to python. Do you mean it's not a good idea to use variable for "for variable in list:" part? I only wrote "variable" in the question. That's different in my actual script

Comment: `list` and `dict` are the python lists & dictionaries. Redefining them as variables means that you cannot use them to define new lists or dicts in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to sort the lists,if you do not have the lists already sorted, sort the search list and for each element in the search list check the headers of all the other lists. Complexity is `n*m*c+c*m*log(m)`, where n is you search list size, m the maximum sublists sizes and c the number of such lists.

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.chain` to join values together (you don't need the keys) and use `collections.Counter` on the values.
Filter by number of occurrences

my one-liner code:

```
import collections,itertools

l = ['a','b','c']
d = {'list1':['a'], 'list2':['b', 'c'], 'list3':['a']}

c = [k for k,v in collections.Counter(itertools.chain(*d.values())).items() if v>1 and k in l]

print(c)
```

result:

```
['a']
```

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple way to check for duplication is by counting:

```
import itertools, collections

t = {'list1':['a'], 'list2':['b', 'c'], 'list3':['a']}
counts = collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(t.values()))
duplicated_variables = [k for k, v in counts.items() if v > 1]
```

You can then do something like:

```
if duplicated_variables:
    raise ValueError('Duplicated Variables: {}'.format(duplicated_variables))
```